# iPhone 5s with Camera + for Blurred Backgrounds in Portraits

Tags: photography-basics, iphone

I've got an **iPhone 5s with Camera + app**. Even though it's aperture is fixed 2.2 I'm unable to take nice sharp portraits ( ***subject sharp and background blurred***). I think this is due to the small sensor (?).  I wonder what would be the best option available to take photos like below? *I don't mind to use an extra accessory.*

[image]

Comment: Phone cameras are not made for ultra-thin depth of field, and yes, the sensor is the culprit. To compensate, you can either focus far in front of the subject (and use sort-of hyperfocal distance) and/or you need to get very close to the subject (if the photo above is from an iPhone, I'd guess that it was made this way).

Comment: As others have noted, it's not really possible to get super bokeh on a phone camera. But, you did get me thinking and I posted this question to learn more: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/96006/how-do-phone-attachment-lenses-affect-depth-of-field

Comment: Issue relates to how the Bokeh is done on the iphone, this is done after the image is taken and cause some issues because it's done post.

Comment: At a glance, this photo looks like the bokeh/blur is probably fake: the spot where the foreground leaf occludes the background leaf (3/4ths the way right, up near the top) — or is it the other way around? — the weird white artifact in the upper right corner, the inconsistent bokeh ball shapes, the crazy number of superimposed bokeh balls in the upper left, and a foreground that looks like it has greater depth of field than makes sense with the leaves right behind them being so out of focus.  But I can't be 100% certain.  Either way, the best accessory for this would be a large-sensor camera.

Comment: Oh, and bokeh balls in the middle of dark areas, where they don't make sense at all (absent dust or water on the lens).

Comment: An entry-level DSLR could be considered an accessory, no?

Answer (score 1):

The way that sensor size, lens focal length and DoF works, there's no physical way you're going to be able to blur the background in this kind of effect with a smartphone. The sensor is so small that the lens's focal length is tiny, and that guarantees a very deep depth of field. Using an add-on lens (which is all you can really do with an iPhone) is going to have a negligible effect.

The only way you're going to achieve something like this is with post-processing. You're going to have to look for an app like Big Lens that can mask off the subject and add background blur with a gradient to simulate thin DoF, or maybe use a tilt-shift effect like SynthCam's.

See: https://iphonephotographyschool.com/depth-of-field/

Comment: can I use a lens kit ?

Comment: @nish1013, I've updated the answer to clarify that I meant "no physical way" includes add-on lenses.

Comment: I took this https://imgur.com/a/2Vld5 with my iPhone 6s and an Olloclip 10x macro lens. It works but you will get extreme zooming. The white lines are a spiderweb. It works for pictures of insects but not portraits.